# Easy question on reflection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a reflection matrix $\textbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ so $\textbf{A}^2=\textbf{I}_n$. I know that the possible eigenvalues of $\textbf{A}$ are $\pm1$. My question is: what can we say about the value of $|\textbf{A}+\textbf{I}_n|$? i know that if $\textbf{x}$ is an eigenvector with the eigenvalue $-1$, then $\textbf{Ax}=-\textbf{x}$ which is equivalent to $(\textbf{A}+\textbf{I}_n)\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$ and this system has nontrivial solution if $|\textbf{A}+\textbf{I}_n|=0$ But what about the other cases?

Answer (score 1):

What other cases? There are no other cases. Every reflection matrix has an eigenvector with eigenvalue -1 (every vector orthogonal to the reflecting hyperplane) and hence every reflection matrix A satisfies $det(A+I)=0$.